# Forge Viewer lightning settings

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I can't quite understand how the lightning works in the Forge Viewer.

The lightning that gets set in the viewer doesn't look even close to what I have set in Revit. The lightning that shows in the viewer after I upload the rvt is very bright, even though I have turned of the sun at set dark settings in Revit.

I am user these settings for the Environment and rendering:

```
viewer.setBackgroundColor(24, 34, 41, 24, 34, 41);
viewer.setEnvMapBackground(false);
viewer.setQualityLevel(true, true);
viewer.setGhosting(true);
viewer.setGroundShadow(true);
viewer.setGroundReflection(true);
viewer.setProgressiveRendering(true);
viewer.prefs.tag('ignore-producer');
```

Is there anything I am missing? Currently the lightning is way to bright and currently I can't find a way to influence it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologizing for any inconvenience caused.

Unfortunately, Model Derivative API translates geometries and properties from the source model only as I know, the light configurations will be ignored currently, and Forge Viewer will use the predefined lights in the `viewer3d.js`.